# Why is community not removing this user profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, users

See [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282658/just-my-correct-opinion?tab=reputation) a very good profile at first look, good reputation, badges, the last activity year (2011) , yes his last seen is in the current month only (that's December '14). Don't know how, but I reached to [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20150711051527/http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow/) and from there I reached to above user profile. I don't know if this was noticed by the community before or not.

My question is, if he hated the community (or a small thing of this site) then why should one allow his account existence here?

What's the reason behind this?

I've usually seen many users with good repo (or they're just learning) facing block from asking new question, if we can do such thing for some users then why not deletion of this user profile? or the other users with this behaviour? If they don't like our community they should allow anything here. <strike>Sorry, if I'm go rude but this is not a anyone directly or indirectly</strike>, but this is for my community, to whom I can't hear  anything bad.

Comment: You ask "why not?", I ask "why?"

Comment: I didn't downvote, but by your reasoning, the government should round up and execute everyone who speaks out against them.

Comment: _"... but this is for my community, to whom I can't listen anything bad"_ -- This sounds like the very definition of bigotry.

Comment: please remove the "Instead of downvoting" line

Comment: If his criticism is correct, then it's not problematic but a gift. If not, we can easily ignore it.

Comment: @Hemang - it's about as problematic as you requesting that [se] remove a user from the network for voicing their opinions.

Comment: That's not how it works @Hemang. Tell me why we would have to remove it? That needs justification. Not the other way around. It does no harm. And if you're not willing to hear about the bad, you'll never improve.

Comment: @Hemang So you're saying that the government should execute a man because he hates the government and told a bunch of other people to hate the government? Don't get me wrong, it *does* happen in some places... But we're not one of them.

Comment: @Hemang you keep repeating yourself and everyone keeps saying roughly the same thing.... why should we try to  silence someone by hiding their critical remarks simply because they have issues with how the site operates.  That is not how a free community functions.  That is how dictatorships function

Comment: That's the worst idea I've seen in a long, long time... and I've seen bad ideas.

Comment: @Hemang But he *is* speaking up against what he thinks is wrong: this community.

Comment: @Hemang: But his critics is a good thing. That he uses a link in his profile is not a bad thing either.

Comment: @Hemang: Did you just compare war crimes to a blog post?

Comment: You have been told multiple times over and over again not to call out individual users on Meta in your meta posts. I will not clean your post this time, please STOP CALLING OUT USERS ON META!!!

Comment: Then change your attitude and discuss issues instead of discussing individual users. This is really bad practice, calling out individuals by name on Meta in each of your MSO posts.

Comment: @Hemang: Them pointing out subjective or objective problems with the site, community, processes, etc., is a good thing. Learn to live with it. Has anybody never ever criticized you? How did you deal with it?

Comment: @Hemang no "but questions needs attention" - is wrong. Your idea could have been debunked without any references to samples. And, InfiniteRecursion appears to draw attention to the fact that you have a habit of posting negatively about community members on MSO. Think about that. ***Why should we allow Hemang on our networks***?

Comment: If it needs moderator attention, use custom mod flags which are private. Do you really not understand that publically trying to shame users is bad? And doing it again and again after being told multiple times is bad etiquette. Next time, I shall be flagging your post for mod attention if you call out any other user again on MSO like this.

Comment: In case you don't know, [it has been discussed already on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242447/what-is-the-reaction-of-se-team-on-why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow)

Comment: @Hemang: will I be the next to be proposed for removal?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If Stack Overflow starts censoring criticism, I will stop coming here.

The ability to easily criticise (preferably constructive) the site on meta is one of the best features!

That post seems reasonable and fits well within what I would call (constructive) criticism. It's not "hate speech", racism, slander, promoting illegal activities, or anything even remotely close to that. I see no reason to prevent linking to it on a user profile.

**Edit**; your question ends with:

> this is for my community, to whom I can't hear anything bad.

This is wrong. Show me something you think perfect, and I will show you an imperfection. *Nothing* is perfect, and the more complex the system, the more trade-offs and imperfections. StackOverflow is no exception.

If you say *"to whom I can't hear anything bad"* you are closing your mind, and thus closing the path to improvement.

I have found that assuming that I am *ignorant* and *wrong* is **much** more beneficial. This way I actually *learn more new things* and *change opinions*, rather than just stick with the first plausible sounding opinion that crossed my path. Saying that I made a mistake, or that I did something stupid is usually something I **thank** people for (assuming it's backed up by arguments and not just an insult).

I think you might benefit (as a person in general) by some reading on "cognitive bias"; there is much written on the subject, all an internet search away; [RationalWiki is probably a good start](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias).

Answer (score 16):

Precisely because we value the good deeds in this community, all the *good*, which is useful content, should be kept. The bad things (hate speech, useless comment threads, spam posts, etc) are deleted on regular basis.

For some time a user could have been adding to the community, and that should not be forgotten. They may have stopped, but that's no reason to deprive the rest of us of their past positive input.

Comment: You are right. They even might come back after some time. Why shut the door for them?

Answer (score 11):

We should delete *your* profile because you obviously have a big problem with some users in this community, and you're causing a "smell" as you say by naming and shaming on meta, thereby making the community look bad.

By your own logic, you should not be permitted to remain on Stack Overflow. Therefore I am sure you will be deleting your account shortly?

Comment: For those who cannot understand, this is a devil's advocation.